# Display graduated QGIS buggy?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, style

I counted points in polygons in PostGIS like this

```
UPDATE hexagons SET count = (SELECT count(*) FROM points WHERE ST_Within(points.geom, hexagons.geom));
```

That came back with that

```
UPDATE 1554
```

That worked fine. It updated the new created column with the amount of points inside each polygon (6.6 mio points, 50k polygons).
I started up QGIS to display the distribution of my points.

- right click on the layer
- properties
- style -> graduated -> picked my colorschema and so forth
  [image: schema]
- finally, I clicked okay and it looked like that (underlaying my point layer with which I did the 'Count Points in Polygon' in PostGIS with

[image: binning]

Well, I thought maybe something went wrong with my querry in PostGIS so I checked how many rows there are empty in my polygon layer. It turns out just two rows are empty.

What is weird though is that in the scale it only goes until `999` while there are rows which go well over `100000`. I think that might be the problem.
Whats going wrong here? Does QGis have problems with rows where the value is > 1000?
I cannot find anything to that.

Comment: That's odd. Afaik there is no such known issue. Does the issue appear if you save the data to Shapefile and apply a graduated style there? Are you sure there is no filter anywhere?

Comment: @underdark You mean save as a .shp from postGis? Where could the filter be?

Comment: Yes. Either in the Layer Properties | General, or when loading the layer from PostGIS.

Comment: @underdark I still can set the intervals manually which works fine. `std. deviation` or the `quantiles` work as well. Its only the `interval` and the `pretty ...` option which does not work.